# Download files from url parallely in python

Tags: python

I have some links in a database which I want to download parallely. I tried doing it serially but it took too much time. I have around 1877 links.

I tried this code for running the downloads parallely but it throws an error: failed: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'read'

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import urllib
from stream import ThreadPool

URLs = [
  'http://www.cnn.com/',
  'http://www.bbc.co.uk/',
  'http://www.economist.com/',
  'http://nonexistant.website.at.baddomain/',
  'http://slashdot.org/',
  'http://reddit.com/',
  'http://news.ycombinator.com/'
 ]

def retrieve(urls):
    for url in urls:
    print url,' '
    res = urllib.urlretrieve(url).read()
    yield url, res

if __name__ == '__main__':
    retrieved = URLs >> ThreadPool(retrieve, poolsize=7)
    for url, content in retrieved:
        print '%r is %d bytes' % (url, len(content))
    for url, exception in retrieved.failure:
        print '%r failed: %s' % (url, exception)
```

I tried this as well:

```
import urllib
import tldextract
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

URLs = [
  'http://www.cnn.com/',
  'http://www.bbc.co.uk/',
  'http://www.economist.com/',
  'http://nonexistant.website.at.baddomain/',
   'http://slashdot.org/',
  'http://reddit.com/',
  'http://news.ycombinator.com/'
 ]


def dwld(url):
  print url
  res = urllib.urlopen(url).read() 
  filename = tldextract.extract(url)
  with open(filename.domain, 'wb') as fh:
     fh.write(res)
  return url 

pool = ThreadPool(processes = 4)
pool.map(dwld, URLs)
```

Gives me 
    Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "dwld_thread.py", line 26, in 
      pool.map(dwld, URLs)
     File    "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 148, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 422, in get
     raise self._value
   IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Comment: What is that "stream" library you're using?

Comment: I think the problem with your second version is that you want to call `pool.close()` and `pool.join()` (or, better, just use a `with` statement, if that works in your version… I forget when multiprocessing `Pool`s became context managers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea what that `stream.ThreadPool` is that you're using, or what its API is… but the problem is obvious:

```
res = urllib.urlretrieve(url).read()
```

If you look at the doc for [`urlretrieve`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve):

> Return a tuple (filename, headers) where filename is the local file name under which the object can be found…

You obviously can't call `read` on that. If you want to download to a local file, using this legacy API, and then read that file, you *can*:

```
filename, headers = urllib.urlretrieve(url)
with open(filename) as f:
    res = f.read()
```

But why? Just use [`urllib2.urlopen`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen), which "returns a file-like object with two additional methods", so you can just call `read` on it, and you won't be creating a temporary file, and you're not using an old function that wasn't quite designed right that nobody has maintained in years.

---

But Python has a nice [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor-example) built into the standard library. And if you look at the very first example they show you, it's exactly what you're trying to do.

Unfortunately, you're using Python 2.x, which doesn't have the `concurrent.futures` module. Fortunately, there is a [backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/futures) on PyPI that works with 2.5+.

Python also has `multiprocessing.dummy.Pool` (also available under the undocumented, but probably more readable, name `multiprocessing.ThreadPool`). But if you're willing to go outside the stdlib for some module that you apparently aren't sure how to use and that I've never heard of, I'm guessing you won't have any problem using `futures`. So:

```
import futures
import urllib2

URLs = [
  'http://www.cnn.com/',
  'http://www.bbc.co.uk/',
  'http://www.economist.com/',
  'http://nonexistant.website.at.baddomain/',
  'http://slashdot.org/',
  'http://reddit.com/',
  'http://news.ycombinator.com/'
 ]

def load_url(url):
    return urllib2.urlopen(url).read()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=7) as executor:
        fmap = dict((executor.submit(load_url, url), url) for url in URLs)
        for f in futures.as_completed(fmap):
            url = fmap[f]
            try:
                content = f.result()
            except Exception as exception:
                print '%r failed: %s' % (url, exception)
            else:
                print '%r is %d bytes' % (url, len(content))
```

Comment: Throws an error at this line: fmap = {executor.submit(load_url, url): url for url in URLS}

Comment: fmap = {executor.submit(load_url, url): url for url in URLs}
                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @wannaC: Ah, Python 2.6 I'll bet, right? So you don't have dict comprehensions. Edited (but not tested; please let me know). Really, the whole dict of futures: URLs thing is overly complicated; I just did it that way to mirror the example in the docs…

Comment: Yep it's 2.6
Code works now. ALso it asked me to use concurrent.futures instead of futures. Just one question if I want to check whether the link is pdf of or not where should I check it?

Comment: @wannaC: You want to check based on the extension on the URL, by looking at the file magic of the returned content, by trying to open it with a PDF library, or what? You can do any of those either on the background thread as soon as you `read` the data, or on the main thread where you're doing `len(content)`. The only constraint is that if it takes significant CPU work, don't do it in the background threads.

Comment: I saw that links which cannot be downloaded it says  failed: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request. So the code handles that. Not an issue. Also I need the name of the pdf from the Content Disposition. But that requires me to do urlopen again. Anyway I can do it without doing urlopen again?

Comment: @wannaC: Just save the `urlopen` object in a variable, then you can use it multiple times, same way you can with any other variable. If you return a pair of objects (like `return r.info(), r.read()`), the `f.result()` in the main thread will be that pair of objects. It all works the same as anything else in Python.

Answer (score 0):

```
from threading import *
from time import sleep
# if Python2:
import urllib
# if Python3:
# import urllib.request

URLs = [
  'http://www.cnn.com/',
  'http://www.bbc.co.uk/',
  'http://www.economist.com/',
  'http://nonexistant.website.at.baddomain/',
  'http://slashdot.org/',
  'http://reddit.com/',
  'http://news.ycombinator.com/'
 ]

class worker(Thread):
    def __init__(self, link):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.link = link
        self.start()
    def run(self):
        # if Python2:
        res = urllib.urlopen(url).read() # as mentioned by @DhruvPathak
        # if Python3:
        # res = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
        with open(url, 'rb') as fh:
            fh.write(res) # store fetched data in a file called <link>

for url in urls:
    while len(enumerate()) > 500:
        sleep(0.25)
    worker(url)

while len(enumerate()) > 1:
    sleep(0.25) # wait for all threads to finish
```

Comment: Shouldn't open contain wb instead of rb? Also it downloads just the last url not all the urls.

Comment: Also, if you wanted to expand this to 5000 URLs, you wouldn't want to spawn 5000 threads. The OP is trying to use a thread pool, which would solve that problem; why make his code worse?

Comment: Also, if you want to wait for all threads to finish, spinning on enumerating the threads over and over again is a very bad way to do that, unless you're trying to make sure you burn 100% CPU and cause horrible GIL conflicts. That's what `join` is for. Just do `workers = [worker(url) for url in urls]`, then `for worker in workers: worker.join()`.

Comment: And it tries to save the files with filenames like `http://www.cnn.com/`, which isn't going to work too well on most platforms. (You'll probably just get an error about no such relative path as `http:`.)

Comment: @abarnert Haters gona hate, and yes this code wasn't complete. I rarely go on to Stack Overflow to do all the job for people, some things should be left alone and for the user to figure out. But indeed there should be a thread-pool since there's many links, so i added one. and `enumerate()` isn't to taxing and can be used for this purpose. And yes, the filenames would be bad and who in their right mind would call them `http:/google.com/`, i know i wouldn't.. but the user has his own preference so i'll leave for the user to descide his naming convention since it's not a part of the OP question.

Comment: @abarnert And as you mentioned, we don't know what `stream.ThreadPool` is, so i made a logical default functioning thread handler for the task at hand. I'd rather give him that solution than try to work out what his code is doing (You shouldn't speculate on code you have no clue what the behavior will be)

Comment: Do you not understand the basics of threads and scheduling? Polling _anything_ in a tight loop until it changes (even if it isn't too taxing) will burn 100% CPU and try to steal the GIL constantly. And trying to fix threading problems with `sleep` is always the wrong answer (expect in the rare cases where some API gives you no other choice). Again, that's what `join` is for.

Comment: And we may not know what `stream.ThreadPool` is, but I think it's same to assume that it's a thread pool.

Comment: @abarnert I'm fairly familiar with it considering the successful projects i've created. You can run a endless loop without "burning" 100% CPU, it all depends on the OS however and i tend to not run OSX. And yes the GIL can be a problem if code is being used across the threads. If you are interested in bashing a solution that works but will require the user to learn a thing or two and develop an example code, sure go ahead. All i try to do is write code that's easy to understand and learn from. There's no weird nested for loops within a dict statement and what not. It's just simple, that's all.

Comment: Also, yes `.join()` does the work for you, but i'm much more interested in teaching out what `.join()` do by writing as much of the logic myself as possible. Altho that might be completely wrong in some peoples eyes. (And no, i'm not god nor am i trying to be. I do mistakes, and maybe i've missunderstood what `.join()` do and if so, my bad. But until then, `.join()` is just a sleep function with regular checks against each thread to see if they've returned data)

Comment: No, you cannot run an endless loop without burning 100% CPU, on any platform—OS X, linux, Windows, even QNX. And the GIL problem has nothing to do with "code begin used across the threads", it has to do with burning 100% CPU preventing the GIL from being available to the other threads when they need it. See [David Beazley's](http://pyvideo.org/video/353/pycon-2010--understanding-the-python-gil---82) talk on this. Meanwhile, your solution does not work, and introduces at least three major problems that were not in the OP's code for no good reason, which makes it not a very good solution at all.

Comment: Also, you're not "teaching out what `.join()` does" by writing completely different logic. `join` does _not_ use polling, or `sleep`-waiting as you describe. It tells the kernel's thread scheduler to block your thread, not wasting any resources or even waking you up, until the thread you're waiting on is done. Google for basic thread management; `join`, and other blocking calls like waiting on a `Lock`, are essential to threaded programming, and if you don't even know what they do, you really need to learn.

Answer (score 0):

`urllib.urlretrieve(url).read()` should be  `urllib.urlopen(url).read()`

Answer (score 0):

What about using `multiprocessing` ?

Sample code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import sys
import urllib
from multiprocessing import Pool

import os

POOL = 8
PDFS_DOWNLOAD_DIR = 'pdfs'
PDF_LINKS = sys.argv[1]


class DownloadFiles(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.pdf_links = self.read_links_from_file()
        self.create_download_dir()

    def create_download_dir(self):
        try:
            if not os.path.exists(PDFS_DOWNLOAD_DIR):
                os.makedirs(PDFS_DOWNLOAD_DIR)
        except IOError as e:
            exit()

    def read_links_from_file(self):
        try:
            with open(PDF_LINKS, 'r') as f:
                return list(set([x.strip() for x in f]))
        except (IndexError, IOError) as e:
            exit()

    def get_file(self, link):

        filename = link.split('/')[-2]

        print('Downloading file --> "{filename}"'.format(
            filename=filename
        ))

        urllib.urlretrieve(link, filename='{pdfs_data}/{filename}'.format(
            pdfs_data=PDFS_DOWNLOAD_DIR,
            filename=filename
        ))

    def download(self):

        pool = Pool(POOL)
        pool.map(self.get_file, self.pdf_links)

        pool.close()
        pool.join()

        print('\nSuccessfully downloaded files from given source!\n')


d = DownloadFiles()
d.download()
```